# Paypal IPN Listener Help Needed

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Good day everyone,
I've ran into some trouble with PayPal IPN. It appears PayPal does reach my PHP listener and gets a 200 return, and once the transaction is finished, I am returned to my website and get a positive message, that my transaction was successful, but the account is not credited with the purchased goods. I've pretty much hit a wall and I'm unsure of what might be the problem. Am I using outdated commands? Anything seems unusual? Thanks for your time!

```
<?php
require_once('globals_nonauth.php');

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
}
else
{
    fputs($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            $txn_db = $db->escape(stripslashes($txn_id));
            // check the payment_status is Completed
            if ($payment_status != "Completed")
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            $dp_check =
                    $db->query(
                            "SELECT COUNT(`dpID`)
                             FROM `dps_accepted`
                             WHERE `dpTXN` = '{$txn_db}'");
            if ($db->fetch_single($dp_check) > 0)
            {
                $db->free_result($dp_check);
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            $db->free_result($dp_check);
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            if ($receiver_email != $set['paypal'])
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            if ($payment_currency != "USD")
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            // parse for pack
            $packr = explode('|', $item_name);
            if (str_replace("www.", "", $packr[0])
                    != str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            if ($packr[1] != "DP")
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            $pack = $packr[2];
            if ($pack != 1 and $pack != 2 and $pack != 3 and $pack != 4
                    and $pack != 5)
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            if (($pack == 1 || $pack == 2 || $pack == 3)
                    && $payment_amount != "3.00")
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            if ($pack == 4 && $payment_amount != "5.00")
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            if ($pack == 5 && $payment_amount != "10.00")
            {
                fclose($fp);
                die("");
            }
            // grab IDs
            $buyer = abs((int) $packr[3]);
            $for = $buyer;
            // all seems to be in order, credit it.
            if ($pack == 1)
            {
                $db->query(
                        "UPDATE `users` AS `u`
                         LEFT JOIN `userstats` AS `us`
                         ON `u`.`userid` = `us`.`userid`
                         SET `u`.`money` = `u`.`money` + 5000,
                         `u`.`crystals` = `u`.`crystals` + 50,
                         `us`.`IQ` = `us`.`IQ` + 50,
                         `u`.`donatordays` = `u`.`donatordays` + 30
                         WHERE `u`.`userid` = {$for}");
                $d = 30;
                $t = "standard";
            }
            else if ($pack == 2)
            {
                $db->query(
                        "UPDATE `users` AS `u`
                         SET `u`.`crystals` = `u`.`crystals` + 100,
                         `u`.`donatordays` = `u`.`donatordays` + 30
                         WHERE `u`.`userid` = {$for}");
                $d = 30;
                $t = "crystals";
            }
            else if ($pack == 3)
            {
                $db->query(
                        "UPDATE `users` AS `u`
                         LEFT JOIN `userstats` AS `us`
                         ON `u`.`userid` = `us`.`userid`
                         SET `us`.`IQ` = `us`.`IQ` + 50,
                         `u`.`donatordays` = `u`.`donatordays` + 30
                         WHERE `u`.`userid` = {$for}");
                $d = 30;
                $t = "iq";
            }
            else if ($pack == 4)
            {
                $db->query(
                        "UPDATE `users` AS `u`
                         LEFT JOIN `userstats` AS `us`
                         ON `u`.`userid` = `us`.`userid`
                         SET `u`.`money` = `u`.`money` + 15000,
                         `u`.`crystals` = `u`.`crystals` + 75,
                         `us`.`IQ` = `us`.`IQ` + 80,
                         `u`.`donatordays` = `u`.`donatordays` + 55
                         WHERE `u`.`userid` = {$for}");
                $d = 55;
                $t = "fivedollars";
            }
            else if ($pack == 5)
            {
                $db->query(
                        "UPDATE `users` AS `u`
                         LEFT JOIN `userstats` AS `us`
                         ON `u`.`userid` = `us`.`userid`
                         SET `u`.`money` = `u`.`money` + 35000,
                         `u`.`crystals` = `u`.`crystals` + 160,
                         `us`.`IQ` = `us`.`IQ` + 180,
                         `u`.`donatordays` = `u`.`donatordays` + 115
                         WHERE `u`.`userid` = {$for}");
                $d = 115;
                $t = "tendollars";
            }
            // process payment
            event_add($for,
                    "Your \${$payment_amount} Pack {$pack} Donator Pack has been successfully credited to you.",
                    $c);
            $db->query(
                    "INSERT INTO `dps_accepted`
                     VALUES(NULL, {$buyer}, {$for}, '$t', " . time()
                            . ", '$txn_db')");
        }
        else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0)
        {
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to make an HTTP request using `fsockopen`?!? Why is this not using cURL or Guzzle or something? Connecting to `www.paypal.com` on port `80` seems pretty off to begin with; I doubt they will want to speak plain HTTP with your system and not HTTPS, when it comes to exchanging such critical information …

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment! What HTTPS version is a good idea to use and what PayPal port would be a good choice in this case? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Unless they explicitly told you in the documentation somewhere that you need to use a specific non-standard port, HTTPS should just be 443. But again, _don’t_ do this via `fsockopen`, that makes little sense.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try and test around with different methods.

Comment: By using different ports and different HTTPS links I got my system to work as intended, buyers are instantly credited after their purchase! Thank you everyone for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of PayPal receiving a 200, the IPN has been successfully sent, so you need to debug your code. Log every step to a file, test IPNs using the simulator or with sandbox mode transactions (check for test_ipn=1, use this to determine whether to post back to the "sandbox." endpoint, and don't break if a test IPN doesn't verify--just log it) -- and thus using your logging output, figure out where the hangup is as far as processing your business logic successfully.